# How to show derivatives rules?

Tags: analysis

Hey guys could someone provide me a nice solution for the rule questions...I just dont get them at all....I was able to answer the first question...but then its just abstract for me...

For a total function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is the descrete derivative for $f$ in $n\in \mathbb{N}$ defined as

$$f´(n) := f(n+1)-f(n)$$

a) Find a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with f´(n)=f(n) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

-----> Here I would say its $f(x)=0$

b) Find a the easiest possible  summation rule for the descrete derivative

c) Find a the easiest possible product rule  for the descrete derivative

d) Find a the easiest possible chain rule for the descrete derivative

THX You a lot in advance

Jacky...

Comment: In (a) $x=\cdots$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), the already-suggested $f(n)=2^n=f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(n)$ is quite effective, which generalizes to $f(n)=2^nf(0)$.

For part (b), the "summation rule" is presumably a rule defining $(f(n)+g(n))'$, which would look like

$$(f(n)+g(n))'=f(n+1)+g(n+1)-f(n)-g(n)\\=f(n+1)-f(n)+g(n+1)-g(n)=f'(n)+g'(n)$$

The other rules will surely follow the same logic, calculating $(f(n)g(n))'$ and $(f(g(n)))'$.

For calculating a product rule, i.e., the discrete derivative of the product of two functions, start with

$$(f(n)g(n))'=f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(n)g(n)$$

Adding and subtracting a common term like $f(n+1)g(n)$ produces

$$f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(n+1)g(n)+f(n+1)g(n)-f(n)g(n)\\=f(n+1)(g(n+1)-g(n))+g(n)(f(n+1)-f(n))\\=f(n+1)g'(n)+g(n)f'(n)$$

But this doesn't really match the expected product rule, so perhaps we can add and subtract the other common term too:

$$f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(n+1)g(n)+f(n+1)g(n)-f(n)g(n+1)+f(n)g(n+1)-f(n)g(n)\\=(f(n+1)+f(n))(g(n+1)-g(n))+f(n+1)g(n)-f(n)g(n+1)$$

$$=(f(n+1)-f(n))(g(n+1)-g(n))+2f(n)(g(n+1)-g(n))+f(n+1)g(n)-f(n)g(n+1)$$

$$=f'(n)g'(n)+f(n)g'(n)+f'(n)g(n)$$

Now it looks similar, and in fact it actually matches the limit form of the derivative, since in the derivative the $f'(x)g'(x)$ term only goes to zero as the limit is reached and is removed because of this.

Expanding the chain rule $(f(g(n)))'$ would follow a similar process.

Comment: Thank you...I`m still confused with c&d...but thank you for the nice explanation

Comment: I have updated for part (c).

Answer (score 2):

For part (a), we could solve
$$f'(n)=f(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$$
so we just need any function where
$$f(n+1)=2f(n)$$
so our function doubles every step.

Part (b) was done earlier.

For part (c), consider
$$\begin{align}
(fg)'(n)&=(fg)(n+1)-(fg)(n)\\
&=f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(n)g(n)\\
&=\big(f(n+1)-f(n)\big)\big(g(n+1)+g(n)\big)+f(n)g(n+1)-f(n+1)g(n)\\
&=\big(f(n+1)-f(n)\big)\big(g(n+1)+g(n)\big)+\big(g(n+1)-g(n)\big)\big(f(n)+f(n+1)\big)+f(n)g(n)-f(n+1)g(n+1)\\
&=f'(n)\big(g(n+1)+g(n)\big)+g'(n)\big(f(n+1)+f(n)\big)+f(n)g(n)-f(n+1)g(n+1)\\
\end{align}$$

Not pretty, but it can be simplified more, it's just algebra from here on out...

Answer (score 2):

For (b), obviously:
$$
(f+g)'(n)=(f+g)(n+1)-(f+g)(n)=(f(n+1)+g(n+1))-(f(n)+g(n))=
(f(n+1)-f(n))+(g(n+1)-g(n))=f'(n)+g'(n)
$$
Try yourself (c) now.

EDIT: The answers to (a) are correct but the **general** solution is $2^nf(0)$.

EDIT:
$$
(fg)'(n)=f(n+1)g(n+1)-f(n)g(n)=\cdots
$$

Comment: I'm embarrassed now...

Comment: Thank you so much, however I just dont know where to begin for c and d...I think  I´m just to constrained